# ImageView causes lag

Tags: java, android, imageview, lag

I have a ImageView in my app. Everything was fine with the first version of my image:
[Version 1 of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O34T.png). But when I updated the image: [Version 2 of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A4G2.png), my GUI starts to lag!

For example the animation of a button-click is just displayed with 3~4 frames!

But for me it makes no sense. Both images are png and have a transparent background. The image that causes the lags is even smaller than the old one.

Comment: Which drawable folder contains your png?

Comment: I just put it in the default drawable folder. Just like [this](http://puu.sh/ndJ2X/7a3e8c36ff.png).

Comment: You must put these images to folders like "drawable-xxhdpi","drawable-xhdpi","drawable-hdpi" etc... If you resize images for different dpi values, your app uses less memory.

Answer (score 4):

Move the image to a drawable-nodpi folder and see if it makes a difference.  Ideally you should put different size images for different resolutions in different folders so that scaling does not cause lags.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use larger image like that. Because of size the phone lag so much. 
In my experience i use the following rules:

- if image bigger than 1080x1920 (today many phone has similar resolution) I convert image into a JPG image
- if smaller, I keep going to use PNG