# How to use scrollview in Android without lagging

Tags: android, optimization, uiscrollview, scrollview, lag

I was trying to optimize one of my app and I had this issue:
I have 2 IDENTICAL scrollView layouts, the only difference between those two layouts is the background image.
One layout has, as background, one image of a size of about 400kb.
The second layout has, as background, one image of size of about 300kb.

The layout with the image of 400kb is smooth and clean
While the layout with the image of 300kb is slow and laggy.

I don't understand the reason of this strange behavior... Can you guys help me?

This is a layout example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pergamena_background_2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/storica_baldr" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="blablabla"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/almendra_italic" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/baldr_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="55dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="55dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/Baldr1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/text_divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/baldr_textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="55dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="55dp"
                android:paddingBottom="45dp"
                android:text="@string/Baldr2"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try to put same non-laggy image even in the laggy ScrollView and check the result. If the lag persist it means that something is done in the ScrollView/content. Instead, if the laggy gone away it means that the image is the problem. Maybe a transparent/alpha channel?

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: Try using https://github.com/bumptech/glide, as it will do a lot good work for You

Comment: I added a layout example

Comment: The problem IS the image but, as I said, I don't understand why. Especially because this image is lighter than the first one...

Answer (score 1):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511334/9130499) the best way to solve this is to move your images to **drawable-nodpi** folder.
for me this worked.

Answer (score 0):

The difference might occcur because of:

- different filename extension
- different drive (with various read speed)

But Your true problem might be just wrong app architecture.

Comment: The problem is not the different filename extension

Comment: And neither a different drive test